# dd-wrt v24sp2 std. on WRT54GL v1.1 - remote access do not work (neither ssh not web-interface)

Tags: router, ssh, dd-wrt, sshd

After installing the standard version of dd-wrt v24 sp2, I lost the ability to remote-access the router.

The sshd is running and remote ssh is enabled.  I can ssh into the router from the LAN, and also from a LAN computer calling the external IP of the router. However, when trying to connect from WAN, I get timeout errors.

Same happen with the http access. If I enable it, I still can't get to the router from WAN. (and I wouldn't want to anyway, I prefer to SSH)

I can't be something external to the router, as before this install, I was able to access the remote-web-GUI when I had the dd-wrt mini, and with the original linksys firmware.

Is there any firewall rule or anything that I should care about?
is it possible that port 22 (for ssh) is closed everywhere (I tried from various places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to, I recommend non-standard ports for your SSH once you get the router back up and going.

You might want to get back to v24 sp1, as sp2 seems to be still in development. If it's 99% vanilla and the only thing you've touched is wireless settings, I'd wager that this is a software bug and a rollback to the previous version would help.

Is there a specific feature in v24 sp2 that isn't in sp1?

Comment: donno.  it simply look as the preferred download on dd-wrt's homepage. Anyway, Ill give sp1 a shot

Comment: hmm sp1 appear to be working now.
it has some other weird quirks though, so I might re-try sp2 again sometime.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that a firewall updated itself and locked you out. Firewall rules will depend on the particular one that you have installed.

If it's not a software, you can reset the router in a few ways, assuming that this is a simple enough network to reconfigure. You wouldn't want to cause yourself a headache of resetting a complex network.

Comment: since installing the firmware, the only thing I did on top of changing the user/password, was to block wireless access except for my laptop's MAC

apart from that it's all vanilla install, so I wouldn't mind resetting (the 30 seconds reset, I wouldn't need 30-30-30 here)

However, I do not believe it will help, since as I said, it is 99% vanilla anyway

Comment: OK, but hey, you never know.